# Un-Escaping double quotes in a Common Lisp string

Tags: syntax, lisp, common-lisp

For generating a string command for using in `uiop:run-command` I need to have a string which contains other strings (as required by the command in question). However the command (Fontforg's legacy scripting language) requires that some strings are enclosed in double quotes, e.g.:

```lisp
"fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Print("A Doublequote String")'"
```

How can I get such a string with the "A Doublequote String" being literally part of the command-string, i.e. no doublequote being escaped?

**Update**

To be more concrete, the command I want to send to `uiop:run-command` is `fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1);SelectAll();foreach Print(GlyphInfo("Name")); endloop' haydn-11.svg`, where the `"Name"` argument to GlyphInfo should be written with double quotes. Using escape characters backslash to preserve the quotes

```lisp
(uiop:run-program
 (format nil
     "fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1);SelectAll();foreach Print(GlyphInfo(\"Name\")); endloop' haydn-11.svg")
 :output t)
```

the subprocess command exits with error code 1:

```sh
Subprocess with command "fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1);SelectAll();foreach Print(GlyphInfo(\"Name\")); endloop' haydn-11.svg"
 exited with error code 1
   [Condition of type UIOP/RUN-PROGRAM:SUBPROCESS-ERROR]
```

I suppose the command is seeing the escape characters too, and that is why it fails to perform, since otherwise the command is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Single Escape Character](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_adf.htm):

> Backslash is a single escape character in standard syntax.

I.e., what you are looking for is

```
"fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Print(\"A Doublequote String\")'"
```

Note that by default [`*print-escape*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_esc.htm) is `t`, i.e., the above string will be *printed* with backslashes even though the string itself does *not* contain it:

```
(defparameter s (string #\"))
s
==> "\""
(length s)
==> 1
(char s 0)
==> #\"
```

Comment: That was what I did first, but the escape \ is contained in the resulting string, which causes the command to be invalid (synthactic). See update above.

Comment: The escape is *not* in the string: `(char "\"" 0)` is `#\"`: the double-quote character, and `(length "\"")` is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have `fontforge`, but I can do the equivalent.  First of all the way you are doing it is not one, but two levels of language-in-a-string: the shell language is in a string in CL, and whatever `fontforge` language is in a string in the shell language.  So let's minimise that by avoiding the whole shell language altogether.  We still have one level of language-in-a-string, but that's a whole lot better than two.

I also don't understand why you're using `(format nil <fixed string>)` to make ... a fixed string.  I'm guessing that eventually you're intending to replace the filename using `format`, but this is not needed since we're no longer going to use the shell at all.

So instead, do this

```
(defun runit (file)
  (uiop:run-program
   (list "echo"                         ; because I don't have fontforge
        "fontforge" "-lang=ff" "-c"
        "Open($1); SelectAll(); foreach Print(GlyphInfo(\"Name\")); endloop"
        file)
   :output t
   :force-shell nil))
```

Note that the command here is `echo`: because I don't have `fontforge` I'll just get `echo` to print the command line.  I've also added some spaces into the big chunk of whatever-language-fontforge-uses to make it clearer.

So now

```
> (runit "foo.svg")
fontforge -lang=ff -c Open($1); SelectAll(); foreach Print(GlyphInfo("Name")); endloop foo.svg
nil
nil
0
```

And this is fine, although it's not clear what the individual arguments are because `echo` doesn't do that.  Well, I have a little utility called `argv` whose whole job is to print its argv clearly, so rewriting `runit` as

```
(defun runit (file)
  (uiop:run-program
   (list "argv"                         ; because I don't have fontforge
        "fontforge" "-lang=ff" "-c"
        "Open($1); SelectAll(); foreach Print(GlyphInfo(\"Name\")); endloop"
        file)
   :output t
   :force-shell nil))
```

We get

```
> (runit "foo.svg")
"fontforge"
"-lang=ff"
"-c"
"Open($1); SelectAll(); foreach Print(GlyphInfo("Name")); endloop"
"foo.svg"
nil
nil
0
```

Note that `argv` isn't smart enough to escape the quotes inside the long argument: it's just a very tiny Perl script I use for debugging things.